# How to store values in drop down list after button click in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created 2 DropDownLists First dropdown contains "TeamName" and second one contain "TeamMember" name. The requirement is when we select particular TeamName from dropdown second dropdown should automatic populates the team member name and after button click data should be inserted in database,It works fine for first button click but second time on the same page "TeamName" dropdown does not show name of department,suddenly it gets lost.So Please suggest me what I need to do to resolve this issue??

Following is the code which I did to achieve this task

```
User.aspx page code:
```

User.aspx.cs page code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindTeamName();
        txtCurrentDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        txtCurrentDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
private void BindTeamName()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TeamName", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddl1.DataSource = ds;
    ddl1.DataTextField = "TeamName";
    ddl1.DataValueField = "TeamId";
    ddl1.DataBind();
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int TeamId = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedValue);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TeamResource where TeamId=" + TeamId, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddl2.DataSource = ds;
    ddl2.DataTextField = "EmpName";
    ddl2.DataValueField = "EmpId";
    ddl2.DataBind();
    ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));     
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertUserData", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkDate", txtCurrentDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamMember", ddl2.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailableBandwidth", ddlAvailable.SelectedItem.Value);
            con.Open();
            int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (ReturnCode == -1)
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Already Data present";
                lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                ClearFields();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Data inserted successfully";
                lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                ClearFields();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-bind the "TeamName" dropdown list after a successful save.

```
//btnSubmit_Click
if (ReturnCode == -1)
{
      lblMsg.Text = "Already Data present";
      lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      ClearFields();
}
else
{
      lblMsg.Text = "Data inserted successfully";
      lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
      ClearFields();
      BindTeamName(); //re-bind the initial dropdown so you can select a new team
 }
```

Actually you can use that method either way, depending on what `ClearFields()` does.